# RIDIC Algorithm decoding

Tags: algorithm, tiff

I'm trying to find the algorithm for IBM/Xerox algorithm: Recorded Image Data Inline Coding recording algorithm (RIDIC).

Within an IPDS print stream, the image gets wrapped in this RIDIC algorithm.  I need to be able to take the stream and decode the image portion back to its original image.  There is little-to-no information out there as far as I've been able to find.

Here is literally all the information I have on it so far from http://afpcinc.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/IPDS-Reference-10.pdf:

"The Recorded Image Data Inline Coding recording algorithm (RIDIC) formats a single image in the binary element sequence of a unidirectional raster scan with no interlaced fields and with parallel raster lines, from left
to right and from top to bottom."

"Each binary element representing an image data element after decompression, without grayscale, is 0 for an
image data element without intensity, and 1 for an image data element with intensity. More than one binary
element can represent an image data element after decompression, corresponding to a grayscale or color
algorithm. Each raster scan line is an integral multiple of 8 bits. If an image occupies an area whose width is
other than an integral multiple of 8 bits, the scan line is padded with zeros."

Any information to work with this algorithm would be *greatly* appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you're making it a bigger thing than it really is. RIDIC is a *recording* algorithm: it is the format in which the original image data is arranged prior to compression. Only if the compression is set to "No Compression" would you have to deal with data in the recording format. And then, RIDIC is simply an ordering of bit groups that describe each pixel. E.g. if you had 16-level grayscale, RIDIC encodes each pixel in left-right,top-down order in a nibble, and pads to an even number of bytes.